# How to edit project build settings via CocoaPod podfile?

Tags: cocoapods

I basically need to set MARKETING_VERSION in my own project build settings based on a value in a json file in the same directory.

Am hoping I can piggyback on Podfile to edit my project's own configuration.

Couldn't find anything on this, as most of it is about editing the Pods configuration themselves.

Is this possible or it's not meant to do it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by modifying the xconfigs manually:

```
require 'json'

post_install do |installer|
  # Getting my version from outside.
  json_from_file = File.read("../package.json")
  hash = JSON.parse(json_from_file, {:symbolize_names => true})

  work_dir = Dir.pwd
  # Get the files and add on my own build settings.
  Dir.glob("Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/*.xcconfig") do |xc_config_filename|
      full_path_name = "#{work_dir}/#{xc_config_filename}"
      File.open(full_path_name, 'a') { |f| f.write('MARKETING_VERSION = ' + hash[:version]) }
  end
end
```

Feel free to edit/post comment or even as a new answer if there is a cleaner way.